# List of applications that require atime

Tags: atime

Without digging into the rationale behind access time tracking, its write-amplification effects in particular for SSDs, or the fact that it can be somewhat mitigated by the `relatime` and `lazytime` mount options:

Can we produce a list of the (allegedly very few) applications that actually **require** atime support, and **how** (severely) they break if it's not used?

Naturally, a number of applications that **inspect** atime indirectly rely on it, in the sense that they report a wrong atime if it is not tracked (e.g., listing or forensic tools). This question should only concern applications that actually **exploit** this piece of information, rather than presenting it, and which **break** at least to some extent functionality-wise if they are used on data without atime support (e.g., the prime example of mails not shown as read).

Answer (score 1):

- mailx
- mutt: "new mail" status depends on atime
  *only if used with mbox or mmdf mailboxes; Maildir and MH folders do not rely on atime ([reference](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#new-mail)); partial workaround: [`$check-mbox-size` option](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#check-mbox-size)*
- procmail
- tmpwatch: deletes files that have not been accessed for a long time
  *usually run on tmpfs only*
- *... (please add your piece of information here)*